# Is a create-react-app website correctly crawled by Google?

Tags: reactjs, seo, create-react-app, google-crawlers

I'm going to build a little shop with React, but i don't know if the google's crawler can explore it in the right way... someone has infos?

I've done some research online, but nothig of actual.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll make sure you implement SSR, which should be already available for React, I think your SEO will be completely fine.

Comment: No, i'm building a Create-react-app without SSR